# How to copy a local file into a helm deployment

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy in Kubernetes several pods using a mongo image with a initialization script in them. I'm using helm for the deployment. Since I'm beginning with the official Mongo docker image, I'm trying to add a script at /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d so it will be executed right at the beginning to initialize some parameters of my Mongo.

What I don't know is how can I insert my script, that is, let's say, in my local machine, in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d using helm.

I'm trying to do something like docker run -v hostfile:mongofile but I need the equivalent in helm, so this will be done in all the pods of the deployment

Comment: In this situation, I would add the file directly to my custom image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use configmap. Lets put nginx configuration file to container via configmap. We have directory name called nginx with same level values.yml. Inside there we have actual configuration file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config-file
  labels:
    app: ...    
data:
  nginx.conf: |-
{{ .Files.Get "nginx/nginx.conf" | indent 4 }}

---

apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: SomeDeployment
  ...  
spec:
  replicas: 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ...
      release: ...
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ...
        release: ...
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-conf
          configMap:
            name: nginx-config-file
            items:
            - key: nginx.conf
              path: nginx.conf
      containers:        
        - name: ...
          image: ...          
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nginx-conf
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
              subPath: nginx.conf
```

You can also check initContainers concept from this link :
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I'm trying to do exactly this, add an nginx config file during helm install. Some fields in the nginx.conf file depend on this install run, do you have any suggestions for how to set this values during install? 

e.g.: `server_name    {{ .Values.server.Name }};` _I'm aware this wont work as the conf file isn't a go template_

Comment: @Kajsa you can do it multiple ways. You can either put config file directly into confimap and use it there via helm rendering. Or using initContainers you can change config file via some sort of bash script. Because initContainers run before the actual container and volumes can be shared.

Comment: I just now realised that this code doesn't necessarily launch a pod with the nginx-ingress controller, which may be running before this helm install is launched. I can't find any good explanation for how these things (ingress-controller pod, Ingress instance, config file, etc.) actually fit together. This config file that you're importing through the ConfigMap, should that be part of the ingress-controller deployment or the app deployment that you want the Ingress to send the traffic to?

Comment: @Kajsa dont confuse yourself with this example. Ingress controller is customized nginx  and has custom resources in kubernetes. This example is only show you how to add some configuration. You can use another image instead of nginx. 

Nope you cant use this configuration file , you should use k8s Ingress resource to define nginx rules which include path & tls & service properties. Instead of defining static single nginx conf you can define many Ingress resource dynamically which can be deploy by kubectl & helm.